# How to split a string based on punctuation marks and whitespace?

Tags: java, regex

I have a `String` that I want to split based on punctuation marks and whitespace. What should be the regex argument to the `split()` method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Code with some weirdness-handling thrown in: (Notice that it skips empty tokens in the output loop. That's quick and dirty.) You can add whatever characters you need split and removed to the regex pattern. (tchrist is right. The \s thing is woefully implemented and only works in some very simple cases.)

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "The\rquick!brown  - fox\t\tjumped?over;the,lazy\n,,..  \nsleeping___dog.";

        for (String s: input.split("[\\p{P} \\t\\n\\r]")){
            if (s.equals("")) continue;
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}


INPUT:

The
quick!brown  - fox      jumped?over;the,lazy
,,..  
sleeping___dog.

OUTPUT:

The
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
sleeping
dog
```

Comment: Couldn't you have used a shorter pangram? ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but this is still taking the blank line as a tokenizable word. Do you know how to exclude it?

Comment: @omgzor: Just add a newline into the list of characters to split on. See the code sample updated above. (You may need to add a \r also if there are carriage returns in your data in addition to newlines.)

Comment: @Neil: If a shorter, but still coherent pangram exists, please let me know. ;-)

Comment: @omgzor: I just realized that you probably want to match all whitespace and updated the code sample accordingly. \p{P} matches punctuation and \s matches whitespace.

Comment: Um, no that's not right.  `\pP` matches all punctuation, but `\s` **does not** match all whitespace.  In fact, it neglects 20 of them.  Java’s character class shortcuts are broken. The correct pattern for `\s` is "[\\u0009\\u000A-\\u000D\\u0020\\u0085\\u00A0\\u1680\\u180E\\u2000-\\u200A\\u2028\\u2029\\u202F\\u205F\\u3000]".

Comment: @Paul Sasik *Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz* was the shortest one I considered coherent at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams

Comment: @Neil: LOL. The coherence is arguable, probably depending one's level of sobriety, but I like it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
String myString = "item1, item2, item3";
String[] tokens = myString.split(", ");
for (String t : tokens){
            System.out.println(t);
        }

/*output
item1
item2
item3
*/
```

Answer (score -3):

```
str.split(" ,.!?;")
```

would be a good start for english. You need to improve it based on what you see in your data, and what language you're using.

Comment: -1 This does not work since the regex expression is not declared properly. It will look to split the string on the character series of " ,.!?;" rather than the individual characters.