# Java .split doesn't work well with toLowerCase

Tags: java, split

I want to split a text. I can do it when I use `String.split()`. For example I split "Hello world." And I get "Hello" and "world" as an output.
When I do the same but with `toLowerCase` I get "hello" and "world." But I don't want this dot after "world".
I tried to split with different parameters and put a `toLowerCase` separately from .split. And I tried to split first and then `toLowerCase`. Nothing works. What should I do to fade away all these , . ! ? etc. ?
Here is how I split:

```
predlog = main.toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Can you please show the text ?

Comment: How do you split when you get "world" without dot? When I do it without `toLowerCase` I still get "world." with a dot at the end.

Answer (score 2):

To keep only the letters and split the rest:

```
String[] r = main.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

To get rid of all punctuation and split the rest:

```
String[] r = main.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Quick and easy solution, plusOne!

Comment: Better replace it with a space. Maybe the string contains no space after a punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

`toLowerCase()` has no effect on dots.

If you want a simple, but slightly mysterious, fix, also split on dots:

```
predlog = main.toLowerCase().split("\\s+|\\.");
```

The reason this works is that split() discards trailing blanks from returned array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601451/how-to-split-a-string-based-on-punctuation-marks-and-whitespace) could help. The code:

```
String s = "Hello world.";
for (String x : s.toLowerCase().split("[\\p{P} \\t\\n\\r]+"))
    System.out.println(x);
```

prints out:

```
> hello
> world
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but the reported effect cannot be confirmed. I have tested the reported behaviour with Java 6 and Java 7 as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String helloWorld = "Hello World.";

    String[] splittedHelloWorld = helloWorld.split("\\s+");
    String[] splittedLowerCaseHelloWorld = helloWorld.toLowerCase().split("\\s+");

    boolean splittedHelloWorldContainsDot = checkContainsDot(splittedHelloWorld);
    boolean splittedLowerCaseHelloWorldContainsDot = checkContainsDot(splittedLowerCaseHelloWorld);

    System.out.println(splittedHelloWorldContainsDot); // true
    System.out.println(splittedLowerCaseHelloWorldContainsDot); // true
}

private static boolean checkContainsDot(String[] splittedArray) {
    boolean containsDot = false;

    for (String string : splittedArray) {
        if (string.contains(".")) {
            containsDot = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return containsDot;
}
```